# R: Not able to trycatch error with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a table with stocks in R where I want to calculate the 6 month return based on `tq_get` and tiingo API. I wanted to use lapply to fill my table but unfortunately some tickers are not available on tiingo or maybe are wrong which returns an error. With this error the assigned data has less rows then the existing data and `lapply` is not working. I tried to resolve with `tryCatch` but it's still not working. What is missing?

```
today <- Sys.Date()
yesterday <- as.Date(today) - days(1)
before <- as.Date(today) - months(6)

tiingo_api_key('<my API key')
calculate <- function (x) {
  ((tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted)/(tq_get(x, get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted)-1)
}

top10[20] <- lapply(top10[1], calculate(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error=function(e) NA))
```

Comment: your loop should be something like `lapply(top10[1], function(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error=function(e) NA))`

Comment: With `top10[20] <- lapply(top10[1], calculate(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error=function(e) NA))` I get an syntax error with a missing `,` behind `calculate(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With including `is_supported_ticker()` from package `riingo` a workaround is possible to avoid the error message.

```
calculate <- function (x) {
  supported = sapply(x, is_supported_ticker, type = "tiingo")
  result = rep(NA, length(x))
  result[supported] = 
    (
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = yesterday, to = yesterday)$adjusted / 
      tq_get(x[supported], get = "tiingo", from = before, to = before)$adjusted
    ) - 1
  return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the function inside `tryCatch`. tryCatch wraps your function and catches errors. This should work.

```r
# Old version                   vvvvvv function call in wrong place
top10[20] <- lapply(top10[1], calculate(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error=function(e) NA))


# Corrected version
top10[20] <- lapply(top10[1], function(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error=function(e) NA))
```

EDIT: @rawr already suggested this in a comment, I just saw. I only added a brief explanation of the function.

Comment: Thanks, but even with this correction I get the following error ```<error/tibble_error_assign_incompatible_size>
Assigned data `lapply(top10[1], function(x) tryCatch(calculate(x), error = function(e) NA))` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 14 rows.
x Assigned data has 13 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.``` So `tryCatch` seems not to work here.

Comment: It's hard to say where the problem might be. See if you can make a reproducible example (preferably one not requiring an API key) with similar data and add it to your question. But it seems the error is with the assignment, not with errors thrown by the API, so `tryCatch` is working fine. I don't quite understand the structure of your data.

Comment: I tried to create a reproducable example but unfortunalety it's not really possible without the API key as `tq_get` with yahoo data is not delivering the needed results.

Comment: I now applied a workaround with function `is_supported_ticker()` from package `riingo`.